# Cancel GWT Repeating Timer

Tags: java, gwt, timer

I have a scenario where I have to refresh a GWT Grid every 10 seconds to update the status of items on that grid. This is the logic:

```
        Timer timer = new Timer(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
               //make server call to update grid
            }
        };

        timer.scheduleRepeating(10000);
```

My problem is this: The timer gets started when this grid is in view, that is when the presenter has been called, but there is no way to stop the timer. Navigating to a different view doesn't stop the timer from making server calls every 10 seconds. Is there a way to stop the timer as soon as the user navigates to another view? It is required for the application to continuously update the status, so cancelling it has to be when the grid is no longer in view.

Answer (score 0):

In the Widget or Composite (the view) that contains the timer add:

```
@Override
protected void onUnload() {
    timer.cancel();
}
```

> This method is called immediately before a widget will be detached from the browser's document.

Comment: With MVP, logic like the timer is in the presenter, I'd have to figure out how to stop the timer there and not in the view. But this looks promising